Doctrine ORM fails to delete entities from MySQL DB
I'm trying to clear a collection of entities. Here is my relation scheme:
Game <-> GameQuest[]
Player <-> PlayerGameQuestLink[]
PlayerGameQuestLink entity has some metadata about when the quest was activated, finished, and so on for each player. Cascade on Player side is not set.
Here is how my relation is defined:
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\PlayerGameQuestLink", mappedBy="player")
 */
 private $gameQuestLinks;

Here is my PlayerGameQuestLink class without getters and setters:
namespace App\Entity;
    
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="player_retailer_game_quest_link")
 */
class PlayerRetailerGameQuestLink
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private int $id;
    
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\PlayerRetailer", inversedBy="gameQuestLinks")
     */
    private $player;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\GameQuest")
     */
    private $gameQuest;
    
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable="true")
     */
    private $activatedAt = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable="true")
     */
    private $doneAt = null;
    
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable="true")
     */
    private $completedAt = null;

Here is the test code for deletion that fails without any exceptions and errors:
    public function resetGameQuests(Game $game)
    {
        $players = $game->getPlayers();
        /**
         * @var Player $player
         */
        foreach ($players as $player) {
            $player->getGameQuestLinks()->forAll(function($index, $link) {
                $this->em->remove($link);
            });
            //$player->getGameQuestLinks()->clear();
            //$this->em->persist($player);
        }
        $this->em->flush();

//       $gameQuests = $game->getGameQuests()->toArray();
//        foreach ($gameQuests as $gameQuest) {
//            $this->em->remove($gameQuest);
//        }
//        $game->getGameQuests()->clear();
//
//        $this->em->flush();

//        $this->createGameQuests($game);
    }

I tried debugging it inside Doctrine ORM code, placing breakpoints.
What I see is it's really commiting the correct SQL statements. But as soon as commit() returns with success result on PDO connection, all of the entries in DB table are recreated with different ids. I know it sounds weird, but it's true.
Even more weird is the fact that when I copy and paste that SQL statements (DELETE FROM player_game_quest_link WHERE id = N;) to MySQL Workbench SQL editor, they do their job just fine.
I tried running the DELETE statements in transaction manually - the deletion was successful. Also I tried to temporaly edit Doctrine's code and remove $conn->beginTransaction() and $conn->commit() calls, also added $conn->setAutocommit(true) - but the bug is still there, so it's definitely not transaction related.
Also tried placing breakpoints in other sections of UnitOfWork's commit() method to see if there are any insertions or collections updates - nothing is triggered.
Finally, I placed a breakpoint inside vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Connection.php file in insert() method - to ensure it is not invoked during the request. It really is not.
Can it be some rare SQL driver issue?
My Doctrine version is 2.7.1, Symfony version is 5.3 and MySQL Server version is 8.0.36. PHP version is 8.3.2. I'm running it on Windows 10 1909.
Please help to debug if possible

I found the solution using MySQL Server log. The problem was in this code:
$player->getGameQuestLinks()->forAll(function($index, $link) {
    $this->em->remove($link);
});

foreach does not work with persistent collection the way I thought without transforming it to array with toArray() first, so I was deleting links only for one first player. What I thought was "rows recreation" was in fact partial deletion (because the game I tested on has 12 players, 100 quests for each player, and the result limit in MySQL Workbench was set to 100 rows for performance).
The correct code is this:
foreach ($players as $player) {
    $player->getGameQuestLinks()->clear();
}
$this->em->flush();

